# How to hide keyboard when we click on any custom button in iphone

Tags: iphone, keyboard

Please help guys...

I am not able to hide the keyboard on my built close button click

Comment: i am wondering how did you get this reputation on stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call becomeFirstResponder on something which doesn't require a keyboard.